# Digital Nomad Visa for Brazil (12 months)

Tags: visa, brazil, digital-nomads

Has anyone successfully received the Digital Nomad Visa for Brazil?

How was the process?

I'm especially interested to know about whether translations of documents are required and if they should be notarized in the country where I would apply.

Also, can I apply via a consular office in a third country, like Argentina?

In my case I hold a US passport but it would be good to hear about experiences of other nationalities.

- [Official information in Portuguese here.](https://www.in.gov.br/web/dou/-/resolucao-cnig-mjsp-n-45-de-9-de-setembro-de-2021-375554693)
- [How to Apply for the Brazil Digital Nomad Visa](https://nomadsembassy.com/brazil-digital-nomad-visa/)

Comment: Could you share the countries you intend to apply from? Is Argentina an actual possibility? Some consulates may provide different information.

Comment: @sourcream I'd like to try from Argentina. I'd go the US for a bit, if I had to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't tell you about the process, but I emailed some Brazilian consulates in Argentina and one of them (Paso de los Libres) answered that you can apply from there (the others have still not answered).

Update: Puerto Iguazu consulate informed you should apply in the country you have residency. Go figure...

Update 2: Buenos Aires consulate informed you can apply from there, but all your documents must be notarized (with an [apostille](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostille_Convention)).

Update 3: Córdoba consulate informed you can apply from there. They also provided a [link to a page](http://cordoba.itamaraty.gov.br/pt-br/vitem_xiv_-_nomade_digital.xml) with the necessary documentation (in Spanish).

Moreover, you can apply from Brazil, as per the official resolution. The information in the article you provided is wrong. And, as you are American, you can enter in Brazil as a visitor without a visa. Given the current conflicting information provided by different consulates, this is the path I suggest you to take (unless it's not a problem for you to come back to the US and apply from there).

Regarding the notarization of the documents, the resolution does not demand that (see the update above). But if it is not very difficult for you, I would add any official stamps I could on my documents just to be safe.

Comment: Thank you for such a helpful and exhaustive answer!